# ORA-14551 when inserting into GTT

Tags: oracle, plsql, temp-tables

I have the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION repeatable_rand_text(ftype    IN VARCHAR2
                                              , in_val   IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    workval         VARCHAR2(64);
    insert_needed   BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT new_name
        INTO   workval
        FROM   ps_dt_mixnames_preserve
        WHERE  name_type = ftype AND old_name = in_val;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            workval := rand_text(ftype);
            insert_needed := TRUE;
    END;

    IF insert_needed THEN
        INSERT INTO ps_dt_mixnames_preserve(name_type, old_name, new_name)
        VALUES      (ftype, in_val, workval);
    END IF;

    RETURN workval;
END repeatable_rand_text;
```

The purpose of this routine, is to mask names in a database as part of the preparation to create a development database from Production.

We want to mask the names, but we want them to be repeatable so that our result is something like:  (input on the left; output on the right)

```
JOHN JONES  -> STEEL POTATO
SAM JONES   -> LARGE POTATO
MARY JONES  -> WHITE POTATO
SUE SMITH   -> LARGE CARROT
FRED JONES  -> RED POTATO
JOHN SMITH  -> GREEN CARROT
```

You probably get the idea: family name is changed to a random value, but repeats when it is again encountered.  Given name is simply random.  It is the family name that's a concern here.

Arrays and other non-permanent solutions won't work well for us, because this will actually be executed as a large series of UPDATE statements all executed within the same session.  GTT seemed a perfect fit for this type of thing.

Ultimately, we'll want to execute an Update similar to:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET ORIG_NAME = repeatable_rand_text('last', ORIG_NAME)
```

But in an effort to "prove the results of this routine, we execute the following SQL:

```
SELECT ORIG_NAME, repeatable_rand_text('last',ORIG_NAME)
FROM MY_TABLE
```

Now, obviously the INSERT in that function will execute as a result of the SELECT, and that's a no-no.  (And without being able to do that, we're loathe to try the UPDATE that naturally follows.  For all we know, it may fail with a similar message.)  The question is, is there a reasonable way around this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally used an autonomous block.  Those are rarely a good idea, but in this case I think it's just the ticket.  here's how it looks:

```
function repeatable_rand_text(ftype IN VARCHAR2, in_val IN VARCHAR2)
    -- The idea is to assign random values to an entity (such as family name),
    -- and to repeat that value each time that entity is seen again.  In this
    -- manner, we can assign random values without losing associations such as
    -- (again) family NAMES.
    --     JONES  -> POTATO
    --     SMITH  -> CARROT
    --     DOE    -> ONION
    --     JONES  -> POTATO
    --
    -- Parameters:
    --    field-type  ('ADJ'  'NOUN'   'BOTH')
    --    field-value
    --
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    DETERMINISTIC IS
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    workval         VARCHAR2(64);
    insert_needed   BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT new_name
        INTO   workval
        FROM   ps_dt_mixnames_preserve
        WHERE  name_type = UPPER(ftype) AND old_name = UPPER(in_val);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            workval := rand_text(ftype);
            insert_needed := TRUE;
    END;

    IF insert_needed THEN
        INSERT
        INTO   ps_dt_mixnames_preserve(name_type, old_name, new_name)
        VALUES (UPPER(ftype), UPPER(in_val), UPPER(workval));

        COMMIT;
    END IF;

    RETURN workval;
END repeatable_rand_text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly pretty, but you could use an anonymous block:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
    cursor c is
        SELECT ORIG_NAME
        FROM MY_TABLE;
begin
    for r in c loop
        dbms_output.put_line(r.orig_name || ' -> ' ||
            repeatable_rand_text('last', r.orig_name));
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Depending on the data volume this may not be practical. And you could pad the values to make them align I suppose.

Shouldn't you be calling `rand_text(in_val)` rather than `rand_text(ftype)`? This will always get a randomised version of `'last'`, though to be fair it will still be different for each value of `in_val`.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting approach; I like it.  To answer your question, no; rand_text('first') will return adjectives ("Obstinate"), and rand_text('last') will return nouns ("Pepper").  But I can see why you thought otherwise.  Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, yes, makes sense rereading the question. The one line `rand_text()` I dummied up to test this did not *8-)

Answer (score 0):

You might try an md5 hash for masking.  This way the table contains the hash values that are not convertible to the original (actual) name.  I am also assuming that your queries will typically join via an emp_id or similar key, not the actual name.

So update your dev table once for all names:

```
update my_table
set lastname = rawtohex(dbms_crypto.hash(utl_i18n.string_to_raw(lastname,'AL32UTF8'),2));

commit;
```

Note that this is case sensitive on lastname, but you can do an upper(lastname) if you wish.  Hope that helps.